# Why was this question put on hold?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, close-reasons

A question asking if all three words: ["to", "too", and "two"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/306268/can-a-single-sentence-be-made-using-words-to-too-and-two-consecutively-one-af) could be used consecutively to form a single sentence, by @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish has been placed on hold after being rejected for migration from [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/27825/can-a-single-sentence-be-made-using-words-to-too-and-two-consecutively-one-af).

English Language & Usage is certainly not devoid of humo[u]r ([example](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/what-are-some-examples-of-awkward-sounding-but-grammatically-correct-sentences)) so it seems not inappropriate here (I have queried the rejection on Puzzling as well).

Please explain to me why it was rejected on EL&U

Edit in response to answers: would it be possible to add a note to my [example](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/what-are-some-examples-of-awkward-sounding-but-grammatically-correct-sentences) explaining why it is locked; something like "This question is off-topic but is retained for interest"?

Comment: I don't think a community wiki post from 2010, during this site's infancy, is representative of our current conventions.

Comment: @choster Hence its locked state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One question like this is funny, but it opens the door to a lot of nonsense.  On another site (The Great Outdoors), I argued that questions that were  marginally on topic at best  were OK (if they were good questions) because the users could self-arrest on the slippery slope of accepting marginal questions.  But TGO gets fewer than 5 Qs/day. ELU has to be stricter.  Thus, I second Rathony's rational rationale.

Comment: I can live with this (and @Ranthony's explanation). Would it be an idea to add a note to the [example](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/what-are-some-examples-of-awkward-sounding-but-grammatically-correct-sentences), along the lines of "This question is off-topic, but is retained for interest."

Comment: @NL_Derek  You are a good sport!  I can't answer your question about adding the note, because I am just learning the arcane rules of this place myself.  You might edit your Meta question, above, to make this point.

Answer (score 3):

I am the second close-voter of the question. The question is not related with English Language and Usage.

1. I believe asking this community to write a sentence with three specific words is a request for **writing advice**. It is not on-topic. If you visit [Help Center > Asking](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), you can find the following:

> Out of scope for this site: Writing advice (see Writers.SE instead) or critique requests

2. The Original Poster (OP) is asking this community to write a sentence for him. This community is not a writing service. The OP should have written one or two sentences and asked specifically what is wrong with the sentence by identifying a specific concern in the sentence.
3. The question is not clear. Originally the OP asked if the three words, to, too and two could be used one after the other **consecutively** in a sentence. Look at the accepted answer. The three words were not placed one after the other.
4. The tagline for English Language and Usage (ELU) clearly states:

> English Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question and answer site
>   for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.

I don't think the question would be helpful to any of current and future linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.

Comment: As I explained in a comment to @ab2's answer I can agree with this. But I don't understand your point 3; the accepted answer includes "to two too".

Comment: @NL_Derek Please take a look at the answer posted by Trenin to [the question posted on Puzzle Stack Exchange](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/27825/can-a-single-sentence-be-made-using-words-to-too-and-two-consecutively-one-af).